# How to strike through a table row on the click of a button or checking of a box

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, strikethrough

Just started learning jQuery this week.

I am currently working on a basic 'to-do' application. I have created a form where the new 'to-do' is entered and then added to a table via an add button. Once added to the table, the added 'to-do' is accompanied by two buttons. One for deleting the 'to-do' (which currently functions), and a 'done' button which I hope to have strike through the 'to-do' row but still leave the 'to-do'text legible.

I am having some trouble getting the done button to function and was wondering if someone could lend a hand. Being a student I was also wondering if it was possible to have a checkbox rather than a button that when checked, would fire the strikethrough.

Also, I have an alert that fires when there is duplicate note, but it only works after the first duplicate is detected. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //pull new note from html form input & trim for easier comparison
    var newNote = $("#newNote").val().trim();
    var isDuplicate = false;
    $("td.note-td").each(function() {
      if($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() === newNote.toLowerCase()) {
        isDuplicate = true;
        return;
      }
    });

    //after checking for the duplicates, if duplicate, alert! Then slideback
    if(isDuplicate) {
      $("#duplicateAlert").html("Again? We already noted this.");
      $("p").slideUp(3000);
      return;
    }

    //adding newNote into the exisiting table
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var noteTd = $("<td>").addClass("note-td").append(newNote);
    var deleteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger").append("Delete"); 
    
    //Try to add a checkbox with the strike-thru like this?
    var deleteTd = $("<td>").append(deleteBtn);
    
    //add strikethru button on the add click, just like the delete button 
    var strikeBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-success").append("Done");
    var strikeTd = $("<td>").append(strikeBtn);


    newRow.append(noteTd).append(deleteTd).append(strikeTd);
    $("tbody").append(newRow);

    //empty newNote field
    $("#newNote").val("").focus();
  });

  //functionality of delete button
  $("table").on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    if($("tr").length > 1) {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();  
    }

  //Need functionality of doneBtn. 
  });

});
```

```html
<body>
  <!--create a container where the user will add their new 'To-do'-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newNote" placeholder="new to-do" autocomplete="off" />
            <p id="duplicateAlert"></p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
     
   <!--create a table that will archive the added 'To-do'-->   
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Things to-do</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="do_function.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: on click on `Done` button, change css of label in tr to  `text-decoration: line-through;`

Answer (score 2):

These four changes do what you ask. First, set a CSS on the note depending on whether it is marked `done`:

```
strikeBtn.on('click', function() {    
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.note-td')
  [ this.checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]
  ('done')
} )
```

and second, the CSS:

```
.note-td.done { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

Next we modify the creation of `strikeBtn` to make a checkbox instead of a button:

```
var strikeBtn = $("<input type='checkbox'>")
```

and we remove the `style="display:none"` from `#duplicateAlert` (that jQuery's `slideUp()` adds after the end of the animation) with jQuery's `show()`:

```
$("#duplicateAlert").html("Again? We already noted this.").show().slideUp(1000);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //pull new note from html form input & trim for easier comparison
    var newNote = $("#newNote").val().trim();
    var isDuplicate = false;
    $("td.note-td").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text(), newNote);
      if($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() === newNote.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log("dup");
        isDuplicate = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    console.log("isdup",isDuplicate);

    //after checking for the duplicates, if duplicate, alert! Then slideback
    if(isDuplicate) {
      $("#duplicateAlert").html("Again? We already noted this.")
        .show()
        .slideUp(1000);
      return;
    }

    //adding newNote into the exisiting table
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var noteTd = $("<td>").addClass("note-td").append(newNote);
    var deleteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger").append("Delete"); 
    
    //Try to add a checkbox with the strike-thru like this?
    var deleteTd = $("<td>").append(deleteBtn);
    
    //add strikethru button on the add click, just like the delete button 
    var strikeBtn = $("<input type='checkbox'>").addClass("btn btn-success").append("Done");
    var strikeTd = $("<td>").append(strikeBtn);
    
    strikeBtn.on('click', function() {    
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.note-td')
      [ this.checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]
      ('done')
    } )


    newRow.append(noteTd).append(deleteTd).append(strikeTd);
    $("tbody").append(newRow);

    //empty newNote field
    $("#newNote").val("").focus();
  });

  //functionality of delete button
  $("table").on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    if($("tr").length > 1) {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();  
    }

  //Need functionality of doneBtn. 
  });

});
```

```css
.note-td.done { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<body>
  <!--create a container where the user will add their new 'To-do'-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newNote" placeholder="new to-do" autocomplete="off" />
            <p id="duplicateAlert"></p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
     
   <!--create a table that will archive the added 'To-do'-->   
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Things to-do</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="do_function.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'd recommend using (abstract) classnames, rather than explicit (concrete) style or structure dependent names. For instance, use `.note` rather than `.td-note`, so when the style changes, the name still makes sense. Also, use a logical name such as `.done` to indicate the status of the `.note`. This way you separate your *logic* (or *controller*) from your *style* (or *view*). The *model* is then shared.

You could use namespace prefixes such as in `.note-done` to scope the `done` class, as it were, or not. There's pro's and cons.

Right now the query to find anything within a `note` is this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.note-td')
```

It would be better to declare `.note` on the `tr`; that way `.note` is a *container*, with nested elements that you access *like* properties. That way, you could use your code on Bootstrap's grid system, which uses `.row` and `.col-..` rather than `tr` and `td`.

Comment: Thanks you! I really appreciate  the help. What if I wanted to have the strikethrough go away when unchecking the box?

Comment: I'll update the snippet, but it comes down to `removeClass('.done')`.

Answer (score 1):

here is a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ou867kqq/5/
I just had to add... I hope this helps

```
strikeBtn.on('click',function(){
          var element = $(this).parent().parent().find('.note-td')
          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            element.addClass('dashed');
          }
          else{
              element.removeClass('dashed');
          }
      })
```

CSS:

```
.dashed{
    text-decoration: overline underline line-through;
    color:#999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the text being striken over via CSS like so via [text-decoration: line-through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration):

```
line-through{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Then listen to when the done button is clicked and have the `line-through` class added to the table list element you have clicked like so:

```
$(".btn-success").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").addClass("line-through");
});
```

Alternatively you can just add the CSS style to it, but in my opinion having a class you can add means you can remove it as you wish:

```
$(".btn-success").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

After that you may want to hide the done button like so (putting it all together) via [event chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) for the win!:

```
$(".btn-success")
.click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").addClass("line-through");
})
.hide();
```

This click event handler will listen to clicks which occur on your done buttons. Once the button is clicked, it will look for the closest table row (parent of parent). From there it will find the first table cell within it, which contains the text of your new to-do. Then it will apply to this td the class `line-through` and the line through in turn should apply the css style.